# How to read iOS (and how many)notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, tweak

Okay since my question got closed i'll go more in depth, i'm writing a tweak that /reads/ if there's any notifications and if there is it /tells/ you with a sound or custom vibrate pattern.

Question is, how would I(the tweak) /read/ if there is any notifications and how many the user has?

Hopefully this is considered valid, thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of notifications are you talking about? And what do you mean by "a tweak"? And what's with the /slashes/?

Comment: I'm guessing by "tweak" he means "code snippet"?

Comment: Any Kind of notifications that the end user might have. For the slashes, its how i put a word or phrase if im unsure im using it correctly. Also jailbreak tweak sorry

Comment: In order to help you, wee need to know the concrete problem that you are trying to solve. Please give specifics and code that you are trying to /tweak/.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to figure out how many notifications exist in the iOS 5+ Notification Center for your app.

To the best of my knowledge, this isn't directly possible because you cannot access the iOS Notification Center programatically. However, you can get close to a "best-guess" of how many notifications exist. To do this you use the application badge number `UIApplication.sharedApplication. applicationIconBadgeNumber`.

If you increment the badge number each time a new APNS notification is sent from your server to the device, then the badge number should theoretically match up with the number of notifications in the iOS Notification Center. In order to do this, you have to store (on the server) how many notifications have been sent since the user last entered the app. However, you can't reliably decrement the badge number by one each time you start the app with a notification and expect to still be close to accurate, because the user can clear all the notifications in the iOS Notification Center without you ever knowing. So the more reliable way to go about it is to simply clear all of the notifications in the iOS Notification Center whenever you go into the app (which is done by clearing the badge number):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

One thing to note, if your badge number is 0 to begin with, you have to set it to 1 and then set it to 0 in order to clear out all the notifications in the iOS Notification Center:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

As for reading the notifications, you can always store a list of the notifications that were went to the user on the server side.  It's not a perfect solution, but you should get close to knowing what the user has in the iOS Notification Center.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Not exactly but thanks for trying to help, the app isn't sending any notifications at all, just /reading/ them. Its not actually a app either